# Serialization Fail on list of lists using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization, datacontractserializer

I have some class that has a property of type `List<object>` I need to serialize that class to XML file using `DataContractSerializer`.

The serialization fails on `ArgumentException` when the object is a `List<T>/IEnumerator<T>`exception message:

> Invalid name character in
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyProj.Result, MyProj,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]'.

Here is the code sample that fails
The Class that takes the  `List<object>`

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
    public class RecoveryMethodData
    {
        [DataMember]
        public List<object> Parameters { get; set; }


        public RecoveryMethodData()
        {
            Parameters = new List<object>();
        }

        public static void SerializeToFile(RecoveryMethodData recoveryMethodData, string fileName)
        {
            var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            using (var fileWriter = new XmlTextWriter(fileName, encoding))
            {

                fileWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                // use SharedTypeResolver for deserializing assistance.
                var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(RecoveryMethodData), null, int.MaxValue, false, true, null, new SharedTypeResolver());
                serializer.WriteObject(fileWriter, recoveryMethodData);
            }
        }
}
```

Here is the usage:

```
private void TestSerialization()
{
    var methodData = new RecoveryMethodData();
    var result = new Result() {Message = "wow", Pass = true, FileName = "somefile "};
    methodData.Parameters.Add(result);
    methodData.Parameters.Add(true);
    var list1 = new List<Result>();
    list1.Add(new Result(){FileName = "in list1", Message = "in l 1"});
    list1.Add(new Result(){FileName = "in list2", Message = "in l 2"});
    methodData.Parameters.Add(list1);
    RecoveryMethodData.SerializeToFile(methodData,@"C:\serialization_result.xml");
}
public class Result
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

If I do not add list1 into the `methodData.Parameters` there is no problem serializing the `methodDatad` object.

One big limitation is that I can't know in advance which kind of objects will be added to the Parameters property (that is why it is a list of objects)

Answer (score 0):

In order to DataContractSerializer to serialize an object, it shall know the types of all datamembers. In your case, you do not define a specific type but an object type. Try changing the definition of

```
public List<object> Parameters { get; set; }
```

to something like:

```
public List<IMyObject> Parameters { get; set; }
```

Note that, all of your objects which you are trying to add to the parameters list shall inherit IMyObject interface.

Update: I refactored your code up to some point (still in a bad shape) and it seems working, please have a try;

```
public class Tester 
{
    public Tester()
    {
        this.TestSerialization();

    }

    public void SerializeToFile(RecoveryMethodData recoveryMetaData,string fileName)
    {
        var encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        using (var fileWriter = new XmlTextWriter(fileName, encoding))
        {

            fileWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
            // use SharedTypeResolver for deserializing assistance.
            var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(RecoveryMethodData),new List<Type>(){typeof(bool),typeof(Result),typeof(List<Result>)});                
            serializer.WriteObject(fileWriter,recoveryMetaData);
        }
    }

    private void TestSerialization()
    {
        var methodData = new RecoveryMethodData();
        var result = new Result() { Message = "wow", Pass = true, FileName = "somefile " };
        methodData.Add(result);
        methodData.Add(true);
        var list1 = new List<Result>();
        list1.Add(new Result() { FileName = "in list1", Message = "in l 1" });
        list1.Add(new Result() { FileName = "in list2", Message = "in l 2" });
        methodData.Add(list1);
        SerializeToFile(methodData, @"C:\serialization_result.xml");
    }
}

public class Result
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public bool Pass { get; set; }
}


public class RecoveryMethodData : List<object>
{

}
```

Comment: There are a few problems with this - I add a List<T> to Parameters. So I created a new class MyList<T>: List<T>, IMyObject. This fails as well with the same error.

Comment: You are right, the problem with list will persist. But the main problem is that, you are trying to serialize unknown types. Every class in c# inherits from object; but the serializer should exatly know the class in order to create related xml data.